# Add custom loading spinner in ionic v4

Tags: ionic-framework, loading, ionic4

I want to create a custom loading spinner for my ionic 4 app with a GIF or SVG animation. There is no "content" property to fill with html, so how do I replace the bubbles SVG in this case with a custom SVG or GIF?

Comment: use `--background` CSS property for custom GIF or Image

Answer (score 0):

It is frustrating that there's no component documentation page for ion-icon, the best thing now is the usage page here which kinda hints at how to do it:

https://ionicons.com/usage

But here's how:

```
ion-icon {
  --background: black; // or an icon, etc
  font-size: 12px; // etc
}
```

You can apply anything there that you normally can with css background properties:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: ok.thnx for you response i want create gif loader,ionic 3 have content property but v4 have not content property

Comment: @naveenpandi You're going to want to use ion-img, not ion-icon then. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img

Answer (score 0):

```
 let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
  spinner: null,
  message: '<img src="/assets/loadingGif/loadgif.gif">',\\Your Gif File Path
});
loading.present();
```